# No result when Rally.data.WsapiDataStore lacks permissions

Tags: rally

I'm calling Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', params), and looking for results with the load event.

I'm requesting a number of objects across programs that the user may or may not have read permission for.

This works fine for queries where the user has permissions.  But in the case where the user does not have permission and presumably gets zero results back, the load event does not seem to fire at all.  I would expect it to fire with the unsuccessful flag or else to return with empty results.

Since I don't know that the request has failed, my program waits and waits.  How can I tell if a this request fails to return because of security?

BTW, looking at the network stats, I believe all my requests get a "200 OK" status back.

Here is the method I use to create the various data stores:

```
_createDataStore: function(params) {
    this.openRequests++;

    var createParams = {
        model: params.type,
        autoLoad: true,

        // So I can later determine which query type it is, and which program
        requestType:    params.requestType == undefined ? params.type : params.requestType,
        program:        this.program,

        listeners: {
            load: this._onDataLoaded,
            scope: this
        },
        filters: params.filters,
        pageSize: params.pageSize,
        fetch: params.fetch,

        context:    {
            project: this.project,
            projectScopeUp: false,
            projectScopeDown: true
        },
        pageSize:   1 // We only need the count
    };
    console.log('_createDataStore', this.program, createParams.requestType);

    Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', createParams);
},
```

And here is the _onDataLoaded method:

```
_onDataLoaded: function(store, data, successB) {
    console.log('_onDataLoaded', this.program, successB);
    ...
```

I only see this function called for those queries for which the account has permissions.

Comment: If you inspect the response in the network tab in your browser's debugger are there errors in the request?  Also, could you post a code snippet demonstrating how you are instantiating the store?  When I make an invalid query load is called with the success flag false.

Comment: Ok, I've added the code snippet.  All the network responses seem to come back with a "200 OK"

Comment: The 200 response is a weirdness in our API- even requests with errors will return a 200.  Your code looks fine.  I'll look into the permissions issue further and reply soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting any request for Defect.js or HierarchicalRequirement.js?  When I simulate the issue you are seeing the request for TypeDefinition.js fails when it is building the model because the user doesn't have access to the specified project.  This seems like a little bug to me.  You should be able to work around it by explicitly fetching the model for a type for a specified workspace and then using that in your store.

```
Rally.data.ModelFactory.getModels({ 
    types: ['Defect', 'UserStory'], //more types, etc... 
    context: Rally.environment.getContext().getDataContext(), //use workspace
    success: function(models) {
        //your code here
    }
});
```